# Disable Command in the Codename toolbar

Tags: java, codenameone

My application uses one form, the navigation consists of replace a main container.
I have a toolbar with sidemenu, logo , back and exit command.
I want to disable the back command in some specific pages.
`command.setEnabled(false)` does not work, removing and adding commands does not work properly.

Is there any way to disable command after adding it to the toolbar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want the command to be visible and clickable but do nothing, you can use if condition on the code inside the `actionPerformed` of the back command.

```
Command back = new Command("back") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (some coditions is true) {
            backForm.showBack();
        }
    }
};
```

**OR** disable it before adding it to your Toolbar and calling `f.setBackCommand(back);`, if you want it to be visible but not clickable

```
back.setEnabled(false);
f.setBackCommand(back);
toolbar.addCommandToLeftBar(back);
```

If you don't want it there, you can either remove it or do the following if removing it will ruin your design and your `TitleCommand` Uiid doesn't have a background color different from the TitleArea:

```
Command back = new Command("    ");
back.putClientProperty("TitleCommand", true);
```

Comment: Thanks , actualy I want to change toolBar command status to enabled or disabled after adding it to the toolBar .I used "command.setEnabled(false)" but it dosn't work .

Comment: That will only work before adding it. You may try assigning an empty command that does nothing to your back command later. `back = new Command("back");`